# Duplication Issue with for Loop in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, duplicates

How do I fix the issue of duplication in the following code? The first entry is the same as the second for example.

```
Input:
import numpy as np
t_max=np.arange(0,2.1,0.1)
for j in range (2,len(t_max)):
    time=np.arange(t_max[2],t_max[j]+0.1,0.1)
    print(time)

Output:
[0.2 0.3]
[0.2 0.3]
[0.2 0.3 0.4]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1. ]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9
 2. ]
```

Comment: Probably floating point errors in trying to hit the max of the arrange exactly.  Try `t_max[j] + 0.11` as the second parameter of the `arange`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try using slicing:

```
import numpy as np
t_max=np.arange(0,2.1,0.1)
for j in range(4, len(t_max) + 1):
    time=t_max[2:j]
    print(time)
```

Output:

```
[0.2 0.3]
[0.2 0.3 0.4]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1. ]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9
 2. ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is about why `0.1+0.2>0.3` in computer programming language.

In your case, when `j=2` the code is turn to `np.arrange(0.2, 0.2+0.1, 0.1)`.

There's code output below:

```
Input:
    a = np.arange(0.2,0.3,0.1)
    print(a)

Output:
    [0.2]

Input:
    a = np.arange(0.2,0.2+0.1,0.1)
    print(a)

    [0.2 0.3]
```

You can just simply use `round` to fix it in your case. Like this:

```
time=np.arange(t_max[2],round(t_max[j]+0.1,1),0.1)
```

Output:

```
[0.2]
[0.2 0.3]
[0.2 0.3 0.4]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1. ]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9]
[0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.]
```